# How to aggregate functions with groupby in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tables like this.
I would like to `groupby`and aggregate this in diffrent aggregate functions.

```
product sex  age
A        M    10
B        F    20
A        F    30
C        M    40
```

my desired result is like below.
Now I can group in `product`key, but in this case, I must group them by`product`and`sex`.

Are there any way to achieve it?

```
   count(M) count(F) avarage(M) average(F)
A   1         1         10       30       
B   0         1         NA       20
C   1         0         40       NA
```

Thanks

Comment: Use `case` expressions to do _conditional aggregation_!

Comment: `sum (case when sex = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as "count(M)"` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select product,
  sum(case when sex = 'M' then 1 else 0 end),
  sum(case when sex = 'F' then 1 else 0 end),
  avg(case when sex = 'M' then age end),
  avg(case when sex = 'F' then age end)
from tablename
group by product
```

Comment: Just a comment for the OP on the use of the `sum` function - in this case, I would use `count` rather than `sum` to make the query easier to understand (the `else` would need to return null, though).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `PIVOT` as follows:

```
select * from your_Table
pivot
(count(1) as cnt, avg(age) as average for sex in ('M','F'))
```